# Angular array binding to .NET list

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Good afternoon,

I am learning AngularJS, I have a simple application that reads an array from an API, uses ng-repeat to create a number of rows and then allows me to post the content back to an MVC action, although when I post the content back to the Action, my list is not binding and the count is always 0.

I have tried numerous things such as stringifying the data from Angular, adding different headers etc, but nothing works.

Can anyone help please?

Heres my stock item class:

```
public class StockItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ChangeReasons { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my action that returns a list of Stock Items

```
 public ActionResult Get()
    {
        List<StockItem> allOfThem = new List<StockItem>();
    }
```

And here is my Angular:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="NumberOfResults"/>
<div ng-repeat="x in toDisplay | limitTo: NumberOfResults track by $index">
    <input type="text"" value="{{x.ProductName}}" name="Model.ProductName[{{$index}}]" />
    <select ng-options="obj.Text for obj in x.ChangeReasons track by obj.Value" ng-model="myValue"></select>
    {{x.ChangedDate}}  
</div>

<input type="button" value="send" ng-click="sendData()"/>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appMod = angular.module("app",[]);
    appMod.controller('appCtrl', function($scope,$http, $interval){

        $scope.NumberOfResults = 10;
        $scope.fullName = function() {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:55691/api/values")
            .then(callBack);
        };

        $interval(function(){
            $scope.fullName();
        },4000);

        $scope.sendData = function(){
            $http.post('http://localhost:55691/api/values/sendbackitems', $scope.toDisplay).then(callBack);
        };
        $scope.toDisplay;

        function callBack(data)
        { 
            $scope.toDisplay = data.data;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The bit that is causing me grief is the sendData function, as when it posts back to my action, it doesn't contain any objects.

```
 public ActionResult SendBackItems(List<StockItem> toDisplay)
    {
    }
```

Comment: try this:
$http.post('http://localhost:55691/api/values/sendbackitems', { toDisplay: $scope.toDisplay}).then(callBack);

Comment: thanks but this is still not working, it must be something to do with how Angular serializes the data.

Comment: You can inspect the request using development tools in your browser to confirm, and also try to use JSON.stringify to serialize the request

Comment: Your code should work fine. I just copied and pasted it and it worked fine (in an MVC 5 proj). Angular will take care of adding the correct content type of serializing the data if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it must be something on the WEB API 2 side of things then, as I still cannot get it to bind.